# Exclude a row if there is a row of another type, but leave the original row if there's no row of another type

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble making a SQL query to exclude some rows that are repeated but have another type of the original row the data looks like this.

```
id uuid type
73 7ddb charge
75 b93d charge
76 b93d cancellation
```

I need to only have this data, excluding the row of charge in case that it exist the cancellation row.

```
id uuid type
73 7ddb charge
76 b93d cancellation
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you store timestamp in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'cancellation' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.uuid = t.uuid and t2.type = 'cancellation'
                 );
```

This returns all rows for a `uuid` that have `'cancellation'`.  It also returns all rows for the `uuid` if there is no such row.

Note:  This assumes that you have only two types -- the two mentioned in your question.

Comment: it seems that your query has all the information needed, i tried with SELECT * FROM t where id NOT IN(SELECT id from t WHERE transaccion_uuid IN(SELECT uuid from t where tipo_operacion = "cancellation") AND tipo_operacion="charge")

Comment: returning the same result set.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use exists logic here:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.uuid = t1.uuid AND t2.type = t1.type AND t2.id > t1.id);
```

This would select a single record for every `uuid` such that no more recent record can be found for that same `uuid`, should duplicates occur.  Here the most "recent" record per `uuid` is the one which has the greatest `id` value.